# Google sheets script always returning same respone

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, formulas

Still quite new to this.

I have written a function:

```
function maxHousing(actualCost,allowedCost){

  if (actualCost == ""){
    return "";
  }

  if (parseInt(actualCost) <= parseInt(allowedCost)){
    return actualCost;
  }
  else{
    return allowedCost;
  }
}
```

I then have a field in my sheet with the formula:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(
    if(
    row(Parents!A:A)=1,
    "Allowed Housing",
    maxHousing(Parents!D1:D,Allowances!B6)
       )
)
```

This function always returns allowedCost, no matter what I make actualCost.

I'm clearly doing something really obviously wrong here!

Comment: I can see that the problem is actually in the Parents!D2:D. This send through the entire column. How can I just send through the relevant field?

Comment: Please [edit] your question to update it.

Comment: @Ben to only send the right cell you can simply do `maxHousing(Parents!D1,Allowances!B6)`